# Facebook SDK import to Eclipse cannot resolve java/Android imports

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I just imported the Facebook SDK to Eclipse, but the project FacebookSDK has some errors which i cannot fix.The project in the Project Explorer looks like this

[image]

But when i open a file, in this case AccessToken.java, it contains all these errors

[image]

When i move my cursor over these errors, it says "the import...cannot be resolved".Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first import your **Facebook-SDK** to **Eclipse**.

Now Add this Facebook-SDK library project to your **Main Project**.

Steps for that:

**Select Properties**->**Android** ->**Select Project Build Target** -> **Add** -> **Apply** ->**Ok**.

After adding as a library project if you have indicated as a Green Mark that means your library project imported successfully otherwise red indicated it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Have you set the Android target on your Facebook SDK project?

Right click on the FacebookSDK project, select Properties, then click on 'Android'

Select one of the project build targets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the facebook sdk project as library in the project properties and after that goto to the properties of your project and add a reference project which is the imported facebook sdk

Comment: You need to right click on the project goto the properties>Android check the checkbox isLibrary

Comment: If the facebook sdk is checked as a library project,are you seeing a green tick or a red X,if it is X you need to delete the sdk project and re-import it to eclipse and don't forget to check copy to work space option

Answer (score -1):

Use that link to download
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/archive/master.zip

After, get all jars into lib folder.